# Dispatch handleClick() to redux store

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I have list of nodes, and if I click one of them it should dispatch an action (for example `changeName()`) to Redux store, because I want to use properties of that node in another component.

Problem is in handling the `onClick()` event. How to force delegating?

```
interface NodeNode {
    id: string;
    Name: string;
    group: number;
}


    export class Nodes extends React.Component<{ nodes: NodeNode[], force: any}, {}>{

    componentDidMount() {
        const simulation = this.props.force;
        d3.selectAll(".node")
            .call(d3.drag()
                .on("start", onDragStart)
                .on("drag", onDrag)
                .on("end", onDragEnd));

    // onDragStart, onDrag, onDragEnd functions
      }

    render(){
        const nodes = this.props.nodes.map((node: NodeNode, index: number) => {
            return <NodeComponent key={index} node={node} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} />;
            });

        return (
            <g className="nodes">
            {nodes}
            </g>
        );
    }

    private handleClick(d: any) {
        alert("clicked!"); // it's clicking but I don't wany to use that method, just dispatch below
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => ({
    handleClick: () => dispatch(NodeStore.actionCreators.changeName())
});

export default connect(
    (state: ApplicationState) => state.node,
    mapDispatchToProps
);
```

I'm newbie at front-end.

Comment: Dispatch to props, but in that case you will still need to add the definition of the handleClick function in your `React.Component<>` declaration

Comment: @Icepickle but how to provide this `handleClick` definition in component, if I dont want to pass it from parent? Or maybe I should?

Comment: It would be part of the `props` due to `matchDispatchToProps`. So it would be just a question of adding it to `extends React.Component<{ handleClick: (d: any) => void, nodes: NodeNode[], force: any }, {}>` and then you should be able to access it through the props

Comment: @Icepickle agree, but in my parent component still need this `<Nodes nodes={graph.nodes} force={this.force}  handleClick={???} />`. What should I pass there?

Comment: Nothing, your connect is handling the setting of the `props`

Comment: But it will not compile... Error: _Type '{ nodes: NodeNode[]; force: any; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<{ handleClick: () => void; nodes: NodeNode[]; force: any; }>'.
    Property 'handleClick' is missing in type '{ nodes: NodeNode[]; force: any; }'._

Comment: Oh wait, could it be you forgot to make the `export default connect((state: ApplicationState) => state.node, mapDispatchToProps)(Nodes)` export? Or are you attaching the connect somewhere else still?

Comment: Seems to be _better error_ now, when I exclude `export` name from front of define class and add this afer connect definitions as You wrote, but another problem here...

`TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof Nodes' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component<NodeState>'.
  Type 'typeof Nodes' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<NodeState>'.
    Type 'typeof Nodes' provides no match for the signature '(props: NodeState & { children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any): ReactElement<any>'.`

Comment: Ok, I resolved that with specify `connect(...)` explicitly to `connect<any, any, any>(...)`. Many thanks! If You post that everything in answer, I will mark this as accepted :)

Comment: Oh, feel free to post it as an answer yourself, I sadly enough don't have the time for it...

Answer (score 0):

You can call dispatch inside your click handler in case you need to change result before calling dispatch

```
private handleClick(d: any) {
    this.props.handleClick(d);
}
```

otherwise change render NodeCompenent render to

```
... onClick={this.props.handleClick.bind(this)}
```

I suggest using first approach, 'cause in that case you can move binding to constructor (not to use .bind() in render);

Comment: As it is typescript, he still needs to provide the definition of the handleClick dispatch method as well inside `React.Component<>`

Answer (score 0):

You can change `handleClick` from class method to attribute and after that `bind` will be redundant. Also I've changed `mapDispatchToProps` notation from function to an object (it's not necessary =)

```
interface NodeNode {
    id: string;
    Name: string;
    group: number;
}

export class Nodes extends React.Component<{ nodes: NodeNode[], force: any }, {}> {
    componentDidMount() {
        const simulation = this.props.force;
        d3.selectAll(".node")
            .call(d3.drag()
                .on("start", onDragStart)
                .on("drag", onDrag)
                .on("end", onDragEnd));

        // onDragStart, onDrag, onDragEnd functions
    }

    private handleClick = (d: any) => {
        // Do something and call this.props.handleClick method which you've passed with connect
        this.props.handleClick();
    }

    render() {
        const nodes = this.props.nodes.map((node: NodeNode, index: number) => {
            return <NodeComponent key={ index } node={ node } onClick={ this.handleClick } />;
        });

        return (
            <g className="nodes">
                { nodes }
            </g>
        );
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    handleClick: NodeStore.actionCreators.changeName
};

export default connect(
    (state: ApplicationState) => state.node,
    mapDispatchToProps
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply call handleClick dispatch action in your component anywhere since u mapped it in mapDispatchToProps.

```
 this.props.handleClick();
```

in place of

```
 alert("clicked!");
```